# rounded dots border passes properties to seperate lines

Tags: java, itext7

**Environment:**
iText 7.1.0
Java JDK-9.0.1

**Problem:**
The line width and line shape property of the rounded dots border of a table will be passed to a separate line on the same page. The other border types don't show such a behavior.

[image: Round Dots Border Table]

[image: Dashed Border Table]

**Code Example:**

```
public class ITextTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try(PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("D:\\test.pdf"))
        {
            try(PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer)) 
            {
                pdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A5);
                pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new FooterEventHandler());
                try(Document doc = new Document(pdfDocument))
                {
                    for(int i=0;i < 38; i++)
                        doc.add(new Paragraph("test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test")
                                .addStyle(new Style().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED)));

                    Table pdfTable = new Table(2);
                    pdfTable.setAutoLayout();
                    pdfTable.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
                    pdfTable.setBorder(new RoundDotsBorder(new DeviceRgb(255, 0, 0), 3f, 1f));
                    pdfTable.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("hello")).setBorder(new RoundDotsBorder(new DeviceRgb(255, 0, 0), 3f, 1f)));
                    pdfTable.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("hello")).setBorder(new RoundDotsBorder(new DeviceRgb(255, 0, 0), 3f, 1f)));
                    pdfTable.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("hello")).setBorder(new RoundDotsBorder(new DeviceRgb(255, 0, 0), 3f, 1f)));
                    pdfTable.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("hello")).setBorder(new RoundDotsBorder(new DeviceRgb(255, 0, 0), 3f, 1f)));
                    doc.add(pdfTable);

                    for(int i=0;i < 18; i++)
                        doc.add(new Paragraph("test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test")
                                .addStyle(new Style().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED)));
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static class FooterEventHandler implements IEventHandler
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)event;
            PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
            Rectangle pageSize = page.getPageSize();
            PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
            try(Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, docEvent.getDocument(), pageSize))
            {
                canvas.setFontColor(DeviceRgb.BLACK);
                float x = (pageSize.getLeft() + pageSize.getRight()) / 2;
                float y = pageSize.getBottom() + 10;
                canvas.showTextAligned("Page " + String.valueOf(docEvent.getDocument().getPageNumber(page)), x, y, TextAlignment.CENTER);
                pdfCanvas.setStrokeColor(new DeviceRgb(java.awt.Color.BLACK));
                pdfCanvas.moveTo(pageSize.getLeft()  + 10, pageSize.getBottom() + 30);
                pdfCanvas.lineTo(pageSize.getRight() - 10, pageSize.getBottom() + 30);
                pdfCanvas.closePathStroke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `pdfCanvas.newPath()` or `pdfCanvas.setLineDash(0f, 1f, 0f);` or such to reset the state

Comment: Joop's probably right, the problem seems to be related to the graphic state bleeding over. Setting an explicit state in the footer event handler before drawing the line should prevent this from happening. I'd also recommend wrapping any pdfCanvas operations in `PdfCanvas#saveState()`and `PdfCanvas#restoreState`operations to avoid more of this bleed.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I've added the `saveState()`, `restoreState()`, `newPath()` and `setLineDash(...)` lines to the event handler. This changes the line at the bottom of the page from a dottet line to a 'normal' line. But the thickness of the line is still equal to the tickness of the table border. If I try to change it with `pdfCanvas.setLineWidth(1.0f)` nothing happens because the current graphic state thinks that the line width is already 1.0f and ignores the function call. I have to set the line width to a value != 1.0f and directly after that to 1.0f.